# Postgres timezone corrections

Tags: postgresql

When we migrated from oracle to postgres 11,We missed to handle timezone for the date fields.Unfortunately data at oracle DB was in EST timezone  and postgres was Asia timezone which suppose to be on EST timezone.
What could be the best solution for this issue to correct
NOTE:
1)In postgres , We have timestamp with timezone data type,
2) Asia/kolkata timezone is a postgres DB timezone
3) in oracle ,we don't have timezone or offset

Comment: This is going to need more information 1) What data type are the timestamps being stored in `timestamp` or timestamptz`? 2) In `psql` what does `show timezone;` return? 3) Did the data come over from Oracle with a timezone name or offset? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: 1)In postgres , We have timestamp  with timezone data type,2) Asia/kolkata timezon and 3) in oracle we don't have timezone or offset

Comment: Do as requested an add information as update to your question so others do not have to search through the comments for relevant information. Add to your question a sample of the timestamp data as it came over from Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to check that you Postgres sytem clock is right.
To do this run `select LOCALTIMESTAMP;`
This will return a value in local time with the timezone adjustement at the right.
`SHOW TIMEZONE;` will give the current timezone setting.

> ```
> | current_timestamp             |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | 2022-03-31 16:38:09.961988+01 |
> ```
>
> ```
> | TimeZone |
> | :------- |
> | GB       |
> ```

If this is wrong see https://kb.objectrocket.com/postgresql/postgresql-set-time-zone-1064 for a clear tutorial on how to set the right timezone.
If this is correct and all the records in your tables are wrong you need to determine how many hours need to be added or subtracted and whether there are records which have been created since the transfer which are not created with the same time setting as those imported.
You may have to run a query like the following on every table containing timestamps.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET timestamp_column = timestamp_column  + interval '3 hour' 
WHERE timestamp_column < date_importation;
```

For your sake I hope not!

Comment: Thanks and I prepared  this exactly and adjusted  hours according to day light savings script used thanks ----->update <>  set date_created = case when EXTRACT(timezone_hour FROM date_created)=-5 then date_created+  interval '5' hour
                                           else date_created+  interval '4' hour
                                           end
where date_created  <='xxxxxxx'